# Median String using search trees in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, sequence

I need to write a function to compute from a set of strings the one that has the minimum hamming distance with all possible sequences of length `k` from the vocabulary.

How can this be done efficiently in Python using search trees?

Comment: did you write something already? if yes please share.

Comment: I found this https://repl.it/repls/MustyBigheartedResources

Comment: And what us your *specific* question about this code?

Comment: This code takes very long to run, is there